# What is a good name for my fantasy species that's not too long?

Tags: fiction, fantasy, word-choice, book, research

I made a fantasy species,a dragon. It's based off of a Siberian tiger, a bearded dragon, and a fruit bat. But the trouble is, i'm not sure how or what to name it. It's main features are it's throat, which turns black depending on it's mood. I've been searching, but had no luck. I don't want it too long, or too scientific. I thought about naming the species Lucian, but i'm not sure about it. Can you guys help?

Comment: If you're trying to come up with a completely fictional word, something that doesn't currently exist, there is no way to provide any kind of objective answer.

Comment: Although you could perhaps turn this into a question asking what sort of things a writer should think about when deciding on a name for a new fantasy species?

Answer (score 2):

Like the comments to your post points out, your question may be too specific for the site here. Consider rephrasing it to be more generally useful - For instance; Strategies for naming fictional species.

Well, it wouldn't be unrealistic for it to be named by/after the person or people that discovered it originally or based on some of its traits...

Maybe come up with a background-story for the discovery of the species, and then you'll find a way to name it!

**Examples;**

The place; A cave, forest, sea, mountains:

- Tarin Cave Dragon, Bamboo Forest Dragon

A distinct feature of the creature (physical or behavioral):

- Blue Tongue Dragon, Black Throat Dragon
- Jumping Dragon, Biting Dragon

Named after the finder:

- Lucian Dragon (After its finder, X. Lucien III)

Comment: Plus, of course, it may have both a "common" and "scientific" name: a Large Flying Fox is a Fruit Bat, and also a Megabat, or Pteropus Vampyrus

Comment: @Chronocidal, good point!